# How to get Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard play/pause key to control Pandora?

Tags: windows-7, media-keys, pandora

I would like to make the play/pause key on my keyboard stop/resume music in Pandora.  How can I do this?

It's quite a good keyboard, and fairly common, so I figure someone must know how.  My specific model is the `Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenPandora](http://getopenpandora.appspot.com/) has bindings for the Logitech G15 keyboard. I used it with my G110 a while ago and it worked. I haven't tried out the app since Pandora got the new HTML5 interface, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Interesting project. It didn't compile for me right off of source code - it was the G15 libraries, actually - and it looks like it would require some more work besides. If only there were the time for it! I'll consider that a "can't be done" for now...

Answer (score 1):

I was a long-time user of OpenPandora, but I found that it stopped working a while back when Pandora redesigned their site. Since then I switched to using the Pandora One application.

A person named Philip has created an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script which he posted to [his blog](http://www.notunusual.net/pandoraone_autohotkey/keyboard-short-cuts/). To get this to work with the play/pause key, do the following:

1. Download AutoHotKey and install it.
2. Download the script from the blog post above.
3. Using your favorite text editor, modify the pandoraone.ahk file as follows:

   Find the block with the following code:

   ```
   ; Ctrl-Win-Alt-Space, Pause/Resume Playing
   ^#!Space::
   If DoesPandoraExist()
   {
       ControlSend, , {SPACE} ; PlayToggle
   }
   return
   ```

   Then add the `Media_Play_Pause` key:

   ```
   ; Ctrl-Win-Alt-Space, Pause/Resume Playing
   ^#!Space::
   Media_Play_Pause::
   If DoesPandoraExist()
   {
       ControlSend, , {SPACE} ; PlayToggle
   }
   return
   ```
4. Start the Pandora One application.
5. Double-click the pandoraone.ahk file.
6. Now use either the Play/Pause button or the Ctrl-Win-Alt-Space combination to play/pause Pandora One.

If you want, you can also make use of the previous, next and stop keys on your keyboard if they exist. Just use the appropriate [key definition](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) and add it to the appropriate script block for the function you want to perform.

Also, you can have AutoHotKey re-compile your modified script into an .exe by right-clicking and selecting "Compile Script." This will update the pandoraone.exe file with your changes, which you could then call from a batch script, for example.